# Azure Web Service .NET Application: This type of page is not served

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

I have a asp.net framework application running on an Azure Web service, everything was working fine, then all of I sudden I started getting this error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
This type of page is not served.
Description: The type of page you have requested is not served because it has been explicitly forbidden.     Please review the URL below and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.3535.0
```

The website is MVC C# .NET - the error message says its happening "because it has been explicitly forbidden." - So I'm guessing this is a configuration issue. I don't think its anything to do with my code, becuase the application runs fine locally. -

Does anyone know what configuration settings I should be looking at to solve this problem?

Comment: Is your problem solved, do you need further help?

Comment: @Jason Solved.... I deleted all the files in Azure... .re-deployed.... fixed